# How Can i save and Retrieve the Image in PostgreSQL using VB 6.0

Tags: postgresql, vb6, odbc, blob

I Need the Concepts Of Image Saving and Retrieving in PostgreSQL using VB 6.0??
Give me also Examples for this Concepts
Please Give the  Solution ASAP

Comment: Welcome to SO, adding "ASAP" and using imperatives like "give me" is considered rude here. Also your question is way too broad, see the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: see http://psqlodbc.projects.pgfoundry.org/howto-vblo.html